# Trying to offset a value once a a string is found

Tags: excel, vba

So I am using the "find" function in VBA and once this value is found, I am wanting to offset 2 cells to the right. I'm not sure if something is right with my logic, but does anyone mind having a look at my code?

```
    Set StationSearchCell = StationLocationRng.Find(what:="*" & ShortenLocationName & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'If the StationSearchCell returns a value
    If Not StationSearchCell Is Nothing Then
    
            projectinfosheet.Range("B23").Value = StationSearchCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    Else
    End If
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what? Or is it just doing something different than what you expected?

Comment: Not getting an error. The found value will always be in column B. The offset value should be picking up a value 2 columns left of the found value. The offset isn't picking any value up though

Comment: 2 columns to the left? or the right? Your question says "right".

Comment: Should be "right". Sorry My mistake

Comment: What does `MsgBox StationSearchCell.Address` (after the search) tell you? Is that the cell you expected to find?

Comment: $B$705 and yes.

Comment: So you are then telling it to put the value from `D705` into `B23`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes..................... (ignore the dots) I have to use so many characters.

Comment: And what is the value in `D705`?

Comment: it should be whatever StationSearchCell comes to be

Comment: Is `StationLocationRng` from `projectinfosheet`?

Comment: No, 2 different worksheets (from within the same workbook)

Comment: Use a breakpoint on the assignment line and debug the values then. It sounds like there is some confusion over which sheet each range is coming from. That's all i got.

Comment: My guess is you're on the projectinfosheet when you're running this procedure so the `range.find` method is using the range for the wrong sheet. Make sure you declare the target worksheet as well as the target range and set the target range on that sheet, e.g., `Set myrange = ws.Range(A1)`.

Comment: Yes, it would help to see how `StationLocationRng` gets set too.